# Set minimum, maximum and step quantity programmatically for specific variable products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, variable-product

I use [WooCommerce cart quantity won't change after cart update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65714608/woocommerce-cart-quantity-wont-change-after-cart-update/65715142#65715142) answer code to customize some product quantity arguments *(as min, max and step arguments)*.

Now I have a variable product with product id 27525, and I want to apply another rule to this product only,
 Quantity rule details: min(default) qty **`1`**, max qty **`24`** and step **`1`**.

I tried to use the code below, the problem is,
if no variations are selected, the default/min quantity will be 25, the rule is the same as the general quantity settings,
If I choose an available variation, the default quantity will be 24.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function variation_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $sample_product_id = array(27525);

    if (in_array( $product->get_id(), $sample_product_id)) {
        $args['min_qty'] = 1;
        $args['max_qty'] = 24;
        return $args;
    }
}
```

How to change the code and apply the rules to variable product 27525?

```
$args['min_qty'] = 1; //default and min qty
$args['max_qty'] = 24; // max qty
$args['step'] = 1; // Seems won't work use woocommerce_available_variation, but I want to change the step to 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to see the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454392/set-different-input-quantity-values-for-product-variations-in-woocommerce

Comment: Yes, I only want to apply one rule to all variations, that is not the answer I need, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`woocommerce_available_variation`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-product-variable.html#source-view.364) hook has the `WC_Product_Variation` **product object** as its *third parameter* and **not the variable product**.

> With the `woocommerce_available_variation` hook **you cannot set the
> product step**.

**The available arguments** are the following *(source code of the **WooCommerce** `/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php` file @version 3.0.0)*:

```
return apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_available_variation',
    array(
        'attributes'            => $variation->get_variation_attributes(),
        'availability_html'     => wc_get_stock_html( $variation ),
        'backorders_allowed'    => $variation->backorders_allowed(),
        'dimensions'            => $variation->get_dimensions( false ),
        'dimensions_html'       => wc_format_dimensions( $variation->get_dimensions( false ) ),
        'display_price'         => wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ),
        'display_regular_price' => wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() ) ),
        'image'                 => wc_get_product_attachment_props( $variation->get_image_id() ),
        'image_id'              => $variation->get_image_id(),
        'is_downloadable'       => $variation->is_downloadable(),
        'is_in_stock'           => $variation->is_in_stock(),
        'is_purchasable'        => $variation->is_purchasable(),
        'is_sold_individually'  => $variation->is_sold_individually() ? 'yes' : 'no',
        'is_virtual'            => $variation->is_virtual(),
        'max_qty'               => 0 < $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() ? $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() : '',
        'min_qty'               => $variation->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
        'price_html'            => $show_variation_price ? '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>' : '',
        'sku'                   => $variation->get_sku(),
        'variation_description' => wc_format_content( $variation->get_description() ),
        'variation_id'          => $variation->get_id(),
        'variation_is_active'   => $variation->variation_is_active(),
        'variation_is_visible'  => $variation->variation_is_visible(),
        'weight'                => $variation->get_weight(),
        'weight_html'           => wc_format_weight( $variation->get_weight() ),
    ),
    $this,
    $variation
);
```

To set the step to product variations you will need to use the [**`woocommerce_quantity_input_args`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.1727) hook.

> **If you want to set the same step to all product variations** you can use this hook.

**The available arguments** are the following *(source code of the **WooCommerce** `/includes/wc-template-functions.php` file @version 2.5.0)*:

```
$defaults = array(
    'input_id'     => uniqid( 'quantity_' ),
    'input_name'   => 'quantity',
    'input_value'  => '1',
    'classes'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_classes', array( 'input-text', 'qty', 'text' ), $product ),
    'max_value'    => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', -1, $product ),
    'min_value'    => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 0, $product ),
    'step'         => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 1, $product ),
    'pattern'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_pattern', has_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval' ) ? '[0-9]*' : '' ),
    'inputmode'    => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_inputmode', has_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval' ) ? 'numeric' : '' ),
    'product_name' => $product ? $product->get_title() : '',
    'placeholder'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_placeholder', '', $product ),
);
```

**If you want to manage the product step, the minimum quantity and the maximum quantity as a custom meta of the product**, see @LoicTheAztec's answer:

- [Set quantity minimum, maximum and step at product level in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943477/set-quantity-minimum-maximum-and-step-at-product-level-in-woocommerce#62946194)

### ANSWER

To answer your question, **if you want all product variations that have the parent variable product id equal to 27525** to have the following values:

- **Min quantity**: 1
- **Max quantity**: 24
- **Step**: 1

You can use the following functions:

> It works in the product page, in the cart and in the loop.

```
// set the min and max quantity for each product variation (based on the variable product id)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_quantity_input_args', 10, 3 );
function variation_quantity_input_args( $args, $product, $variation ) {
    // set variable product ids
    $sample_product_id = array( 27525 );
    // if the selected variation belongs to one of the variable product ids
    // set the min and max quantity
    if ( in_array( $variation->get_parent_id(), $sample_product_id ) ) {
        $args['min_qty'] = 1;
        $args['max_qty'] = 24;
        return $args;
    }
    return $args;
}


// set the step for specific variable products (and for each product variation)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'set_step_for_specific_variable_products', 10, 2 );
function set_step_for_specific_variable_products( $args, $product ) {
    // set variable product ids
    $sample_product_id = array( 27525 );
    
    // on the product page
    if ( ! is_cart() ) {
        // if the id of the variable product is in the array
        if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $sample_product_id ) ) {
            $args['input_value'] = 1;
            $args['min_value'] = 1;
            $args['max_value'] = 24;
            $args['step'] = 1;
        }
    // in the cart
    } else {
        // if the id of the product variation belongs to a variable product present in the array
        if ( in_array( $product->get_parent_id(), $sample_product_id ) ) {
            $args['min_value'] = 1;
            $args['step'] = 1;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Hi Vincenzo, thanks for your answering. I add '$args['input_value'] = 1;' and '$args['min_value'] = 1;' to your answer, otherwise, the default quantity will be 24. The quantity step on the cart page is still 25, is it possible to change it to 1?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now it works both in the product page and in the cart *(in the cart I also added `max_value` to **24**)*.

Comment: Actually, replace the $args['max_value']=24; with $args['min_value']=1; of the cart rule(else condition) is the perfect answer. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can this be used with a custom field value rather than hard coding the product id?